# Unable to SSH VM instance after OS upgrade & reboot of VM instance in GCP

Tags: centos, google-cloud-platform, centos7, google-compute-engine, gcp

My VM instance was on CentOS 7

I recently attempted upgrading that to Almalinux 8 using below link

https://wiki.almalinux.org/elevate/ELevating-CentOS7-to-AlmaLinux-9.html#migrate-centos-7-to-almalinux-8

As I per formed the instructed reboot post step sudo leapp upgrade I was unable to connect to my instance via SSH

On observing VM instance logs I have some error logs on repeat which are like

```
{@type: type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent, bootCounter: 1000, startupEvent: {…}}

{@type: type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent, bootCounter: 1000, earlyBootReportEvent: {…}}

{@type: type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent, bootCounter: 1000, shutdownEvent: {…}}
```

Any help here would be appreciated for how may I connect to the VM instance now. enter image description here enter image description here

Logs generated
[image: Logs]

Early Boot Event Error in expanded form
[image: Early Boot Event Error]

Comment: Edit your question with more details. Are you using a shielded image for your VM? Do you have Secure Boot, vTPM, or Integrity Monitoring enabled? Research error messages before posting a question so that you know which details to provide. https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/shielded-vm

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Almalinux doc](https://almalinux.org/elevate/), Migrations will require your system to reboot twice. Can you reboot again and try it. If still unable to connect check below points :

- As per the logs you are receiving  integrity validation failure , You might need to identify the cause of an integrity validation failure and [update the integrity policy baseline](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/integrity-monitoring#updating-baseline) using the current instance configuration. The VM instance must be running when you update the baseline.
- If you can't diagnose and resolve the cause of the SSH connection issue, connect using the  [SSH Putty  client](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/standard-ssh#putty-app) .
- To find more methods for diagnosing and resolving failed SSH connections, see [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors).
- You can also raise this issue in [almalinux disclosure group](https://almalinux.discourse.group/) to get in line issue resolution .

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to pass this error.

I had to turn OFF the VM SHIELD checkboxes at my VM security section

- vTPM
- Integrity Monitoring

Above options were present as ON. Upon upgrade the kernel was also upgraded. the `Integrity Monitoring` maintains a record of existing kernel version which was causing the error as appearing in the logs at the questions. (As the kernel was upgraded now)

Though by this change I am able to bypass the error but I am still not sure of how to actually update the kernel records so that the integrity monitoring passes it. So, my approach is more a hack where I turned the validation off.

Do update the question thread if somebody knows about the Update Kernel records to pass Integrity Check. Thanks

[image]